# Visual 2015 C++ Program Not Running, Deubugging Symbols issue?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Just started programming in C++ and I installed Visual 2015. I've been trying to run a simple "Hello World" program but I get the following:

```
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\(user)\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded
'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded
'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded
'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded
'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded
'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded
'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded
'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded
'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded
'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.

The thread 0x2714 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x748 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xc24 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[3496] ConsoleApplication1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I NO CLUE what this is for. The console shows my output for a bit, then it closes and shows that whole message. I've searched the internet but I am not getting solid answers on this.

Comment: This is typical behavior. Put a breakpoint in your code when you run in debug, and it should stop. Alternatively, put a `system("pause");` at the end of your code, just to see the output.

Comment: That means your program started, loaded some DLLs (which is normal and happens automatically), and exited.

Comment: Alternatively, run your program without the debugger (Ctrl-F5 instead of F5) and Visual Studio will do a "Press any key to continue" thing for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with Symbols - can't step into .NET code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625096/issue-with-symbols-cant-step-into-net-code)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your program has been running fine:

> The thread 0x2714 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>  The thread 0x748
>   has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>  The thread 0xc24 has exited with
>   code 0 (0x0).
>  The program '[3496] ConsoleApplication1.exe' has
>   exited with code 0 (0x0).

The first part is about starting your program and loading of all the necessary dll's. The last part means the threads and your program exited with a code of 0x0, which means no errors.

You probably need to put a breakpoint <kbd>F9</kbd> somewhere, to pause the program, or in a console application a `getch();` (which needs: `#include <conio.h>`).

The console shows this output when the program is started in debug mode (with <kbd>F5</kbd>), to start it without debugging output, use <kbd>Ctrl-F5</kbd> (Menu Debug / Start Without Debugging).